# algorithm to use to balance a set of IPs into a set of buckets

Tags: normal-distribution

So we have a set of IP addresses (~3000) and want to balance them into 4 different buckets. What we are doing now is very simple by treating the last part of the IP as integer and mod it by 4. e.g. 70.193.131.145 -> 145 mod 4 = 1, and so that ip will go to the bucket 1). And we we are getting is a set of very unbalanced buckets with one bucket to have a lot more IPs than the other 3.

Is there a better way to do that so the IPs will get well distributed to all 4 of buckets?

Comment: Why not just place the IP addresses in the buckets sequentially by a round-robin??  That is, sort the addresses numerically, then place the 1st address in bucket 1, 2nd in 2, 3rd, in 3, 4th in 4, 5th in 1, etc.

Comment: There are many ways to partition a set of size 3000 into four sets, each of size 750.  Which one you should choose probably depends on programming considerations (which are not really mathematical considerations unless you specify more precisely what the problem is.)